# argument of runMaybeT of MaybeT

Tags: haskell

In https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers, I see

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

and then the instanciation of `MaybeT` as a monad:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where
  return  = MaybeT . return . Just

  -- The signature of (>>=), specialized to MaybeT m:
  -- (>>=) :: MaybeT m a -> (a -> MaybeT m b) -> MaybeT m b
  x >>= f = MaybeT $ do maybe_value <- runMaybeT x
                        case maybe_value of
                           Nothing    -> return Nothing
                           Just value -> runMaybeT $ f value
```

I do not understand the arg  `x` in `runMaybeT x`. Shouldn't `runMaybeT` take an arg corresponding to `a`? But instead it is given `x` which is the entire `MonadT` monad

Comment: `x` is a `MaybeT m a`, and `f` has type `a -> MaybeT m b`. The `runMaybeT` is a *getter*, so `runMaybeT x` will "unwrap" the item wrapped in the `MaybeT` data constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just standard record syntax. In a type definition such as

```
data Foo = Foo { a :: Int, b :: String }
```

it presumably does not surprise you that we automatically get functions `a :: Foo -> Int` and `b :: Foo -> String`.

It's absolutely no different for `MaybeT`. (It does use `newtype` rather than `data` but that doesn't matter here, the same would be true if the definition used `data` instead)

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

this gives us a function `runMaybeT :: MaybeT m a -> m (Maybe a)` for exactly the same reason that we get the functions `a` and `b` in the simpler example above. It's just what record syntax does.

Specifically in this case, as always with a `newtype` defined using record syntax, the `runMaybeT` function allows us to "unwrap" a monadic value, going from the abstract `MaybeT m a` to the more "concrete" representation as a value of type `m (Maybe a)`.

This is used in the implementation of `>>=` for `MaybeT m`: since its first argument (`x` in your snippet) is of type `MaybeT m a`, we first need `runMaybeT` to get the "unwrapped" value of type `m (Maybe a)`, then use the `>>=` of the "base monad" `m` (shown here with `do` notation) to "extract" a value of type `Maybe a` which is then pattern matched on in the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

`runMaybeT` is a *getter*. It is a function that takes a `MaybeT m a` object, and returns an `m (Maybe a)` object, so it has signature `MaybeT m a -> m (Maybe a)`.

Perhaps it is easier to understand however if we unpack the value with a pattern:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where
  return  = MaybeT . return . Just
  MaybeT rm >>= f = MaybeT $ do
                        maybe_value <- rm
                        case maybe_value of
                            Nothing -> return Nothing
                            Just value -> runMaybeT $ f value
```